# Excel Custom Functions suddenly stopped working on local

Tags: excel, office-js

Excel Custom Functions very suddenly stopped working on my localhost (after a long period of working flawlessly.) All apps (our custom, as well as the starcount tutorial) now fail with the following error:

> "This add-in could not be started. Close this dialog to ignore the
>   problem or click "Restart" to try again."

Additionally, at the bottom of the worksheet I get:

> "We're starting the add-ins runtime, just a moment..."

and it never goes away.

**Attempts to resolve**

- Deleted all custom functions and reverted to very simple "add" function [FAILED]
- Re-built app manifest [FAILED]
- Downloaded completely fresh Starcount tutorial example and tried loading custom functions [FAILED]
- Tried app custom functions in Excel Online [SUCCESS]

**Recently installed programs**

- PM2 (https://pm2.keymetrics.io/)
- Folder Size Explorer (https://www.folder-size-explorer.com/)

**Helpful information**

- winver: Version 19033 (OS Build 18362.476)
- Excel version: Office 365 ProPlus, Version 1911 (Build 122228.20120)
- [Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4FZQ.png)
- [Link to runtime logging file. CSL is the namespace](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AkpPaan7mENegsQD2BiMcuzVbxCl_w)

Comment: Did you clear your WEF cache either by deleting the `C:\Users\YourWindowsUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef`or by `Excel > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Trusted Add-in Catalogs > Clear`?

Comment: Hey @ZlatkoMichailov-MSFT - Yes, I have cleared the WEF multiple times after each of the previous attempts to resolve, and am still getting the errors.

Comment: Please install add-in `WA104381720` from the store. Click on the 'Show Taskpane' button. Execute function `CONST_ASYNC()`, Let me know if you see any error.

Comment: @ZlatkoMichailov-MSFT No error. Received value "42" in the cell after running =MICROSOFT.OFFICE.TEST.UPGRADE.CONST_ASYNC()

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! That means the Custom Functions pipeline is working fine. I will ask somebody from the office.js team and from the tooling team to help you further. Meanwhile, if you share how you reference office.js, you'll save some time.

Comment: @ZlatkoMichailov-MSFT Sure I can help, what would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the local custom functions by upgrading to the insider build. It seems as though there may be a slight bug with the 1911 Office build.

- Not working: Version 1911
- Working: Version 1912 (Build 12312.20002)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem last week and it turned out my loopback exception had stopped working. I enabled it again and then I could debug add-ins on desktop again. You can work with the loopback exception from the CLI using the following commands.

To enable loopback for Edge WebView:
**npx office-addin-dev-settings appcontainer edgewebview --loopback**

To query: 
**npx office-addin-dev-settings appcontainer edgewebview**

To remove loopback:
**npx office-addin-dev-settings appcontainer edgewebview – prevent-loopback**

This is a wrapper that calls the CheckNetIsolation tool. You can also run the tool yourself with the following command to enable the loopback exception.

**CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n="microsoft.win32webviewhost_cw5n1h2txyewy"**

Comment: Hi David. Thanks for commenting. I tried the following (all to no avail):

1. Enable loopback for edge webview in Git Bash.
2. Verified "Loopback is allowed."
3. Tried again [FAILED]
4. Removed loopback and received "Loopback is no longer allowed"
5. Re-ran enable command, received "Loopback is allowed."
6. Tried functions [FAILED]
7. Tried all of the above in CMD as an administrator
8. Tried functions [FAILED]